Triying to connect a DB Xampp to Looker-Studio?
Hello all i was wondering i small school DB  made in with xampp help my problem is , i can connect perfectly well on POWERBI , but when i try to use looker studio it wont let me connect. Please help if possible ?
I try using several connecters provided by looker studio no luck.
